# Cannot find reason for missing parsed attributes in Qi JSON parser

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

**Problem**:

1. Cannot find reason for missing parsed attributes in Qi JSON parser. The parser successfully parses the input string but the output data structure, json_object, only contains the first attribute (attribute_a) but missing the others (attribute_b and attribute_c)

**Software**: Boost Spirit Qi using Boost 1.52

**Platform**: Windows 7 (64-bit)

**Compiler** (Visual Studio 2010)

**Request**:

1. Help finding out why the parser is not finding all attributes.
2. Looking at the debugging output I see that the attributes are not being put into a single std::vector object. I am using JSON grammar I found on http://www.json.org/ as a reference. What I would like to see as the output of the '*members*' is a single std::vector containing a list of all json_pair objects found for that JSON object.

**Limitations**:

1. Parser does not support Unicode strings.

**Code:**

```
    #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
    #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
    #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
    #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_container.hpp>
    #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_statement.hpp>
    #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
    #include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
    #include <boost/fusion/include/boost_tuple.hpp>
    #include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>

    #include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

    #include <vector>

    namespace signal_processing {
      namespace parsing {

        struct json_object;
        struct json_array;

        typedef boost::variant < std::string,
            double,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<json_object>,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<json_array>,
            bool > json_value;

        typedef boost::tuple < std::string, json_value> json_pair;

        struct json_members
        {
            std::vector < json_pair > items;
        };

        struct json_object
        {
            std::vector < json_members > children;
        };

        struct json_array
        {
            std::vector < json_value > list;
        };

        using boost::spirit::qi::bool_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::char_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::double_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::eol;
        using boost::spirit::qi::float_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::int_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::lexeme;
        using boost::spirit::qi::lit;   
        using boost::spirit::qi::space;
        using boost::spirit::qi::_val;
        using boost::spirit::qi::_1;

        template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
        struct json_grammar : boost::spirit::qi::grammar < Iterator, json_object(), Skipper>
        {
            json_grammar() : json_grammar::base_type(object)
            {
                object = '{' > *members > '}';

                pair = string > ':' > value;

                members = pair > *( ',' > members );

                element_list = '[' > *elements > ']';

                elements = value > *( ',' > elements );

                value = string |
                    number |
                    object |
                    element_list |
                    bool_ |
                    lit("null");

                char const* exclude = " ();\"\n\r\t";
                string = '"'
                    > +lexeme[char_ - char_(exclude)]
                    > '"';

                // Return: double
                number = double_ |
                    float_ |
                    int_;

                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(object);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(pair);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(members);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(element_list);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(elements);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(value);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(string);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(number);
            }

            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, json_object(), Skipper > object;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, json_pair(), Skipper > pair;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, json_members(), Skipper > members;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, json_array(), Skipper > element_list;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, json_array(), Skipper > elements;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, json_value(), Skipper > value;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, std::string(), Skipper > string;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, double(), Skipper > number;
        };
      }
    }

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
        signal_processing::parsing::json_object,
        (std::vector < signal_processing::parsing::json_members >, children)
    )

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
        signal_processing::parsing::json_members,
        (std::vector < signal_processing::parsing::json_pair >, items)
    )

    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
        signal_processing::parsing::json_array,
        (std::vector < signal_processing::parsing::json_value >, list)
    )

    void parse ( std::string const& file )
    {
        typedef signal_processing::parsing::json_grammar < std::string::const_iterator, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type > configuration_grammar;
        configuration_grammar input; // Input grammar
        signal_processing::parsing::json_object parsed_data;

        std::string::const_iterator iter = file.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator end = file.end();
        bool r = boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse ( iter, end, input, boost::spirit::ascii::space, parsed_data );

        if ( ! r || iter != end)
        {
            // Report the next 30 characters
            std::string::const_iterator some = iter + 30;

            if ( some > end )
            {
                some = end;
            }

            std::string context(iter, some);
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
            std::cout << "stopped at: \": " << context << "...\"\n";
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        }
    }

    int main(int,char**)
    {
        std::string input ( "{\r\n       \"Event\": {\r\n                \"attribute_a\": 0.0002,\r\n                \"attribute_b\": 2e-005,\r\n                \"attribute_c\": 0.022\r\n        }\r\n}" );

        parse ( input );

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You can find [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Unexpected-parsing-result-bug-fusion-adapt-struct-variant-vector-td4418747.html) a really similar problem. You can sidestep the problem using a temporary rule with an attribute of `vector`. If you change the rules `members` and `elements` as suggested by FatalFlaw and make their attributes `std::vector<json_pair>` and `std::vector<json_value>` respectively, you will get the result you want with that input.

Comment: +1 Nice grammar. It looks clean. You should add limitations: no support for character escapes (`\b\f\r\n\0\"`) and accepting non-JSON-compliant numeric formats (including but not limited to ±∞ and NaN)

Answer (score 1):

**The parser**

The answer to your first question, in general, is that there are probably a few ways to achieve what you want. Specifically, I can show you a way that seems to work.

The key thing is correctly setting up the attribute types for the rules that match one or more  instances of a given phrase or token, by making sure that what you declare actually is a container, rather than a struct that has a member that is a container.

Once you've done that you need to compose the rule so that Qi knows that you are dealing with a container, and that it should back fill as appropriate.

Looking at the members rule first: you supplied this as the rule:

```
members = pair > *( ',' > members );
```

I don't believe this in itself is enough to tell Qi that you want it to back-stuff a `json_members` container with `pair`s, especially since `pair`s and a `member`s don't have the same attribute type. So I suggest you replace the rule with:

```
members = pair > *( ',' > pair );
```

Or even:

```
members = pair % ',';
```

You need to determine that these rules amount to the same thing or not, but you get the idea.

As to the `json_members` type: I changed your struct definition to make the struct derive from the container instead of having the container as a property of the struct:

```
struct json_members : std::vector < json_pair > {};
```

And you don't need to do the fusion-isation of the struct.

Here's what appears to me to be a working version of your code:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
    #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
    #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
    #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_container.hpp>
    #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_statement.hpp>
    #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
    #include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
    #include <boost/fusion/include/boost_tuple.hpp>
    #include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>

    #include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

    #include <vector>

    namespace signal_processing {
      namespace parsing {

        struct json_object;
        struct json_array;

        typedef boost::variant < std::string,
            double,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<json_object>,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<json_array>,
            bool > json_value;

        typedef boost::tuple < std::string, json_value> json_pair;

//        struct json_members
//        {
//            std::vector < json_pair > items;
//        };
//
//        struct json_object
//        {
//            std::vector < json_members > children;
//        };
//
//        struct json_array
//        {
//            std::vector < json_value > list;
//        };

        struct json_members : std::vector < json_pair > {};
        struct json_object : std::vector < json_members > {};
        struct json_array : std::vector < json_value > {};

        using boost::spirit::qi::bool_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::char_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::double_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::eol;
        using boost::spirit::qi::float_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::int_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::lexeme;
        using boost::spirit::qi::lit;
        using boost::spirit::qi::space;
        using boost::spirit::qi::_val;
        using boost::spirit::qi::_1;

        template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
        struct json_grammar : boost::spirit::qi::grammar < Iterator, json_object(), Skipper>
        {
            json_grammar() : json_grammar::base_type(object)
            {
                object = '{' > *members > '}';

                pair = string > ':' > value;

                members = pair > *( ',' > pair );

                element_list = '[' > *elements > ']';

                elements = value > *( ',' > value );

                value = string |
                    number |
                    object |
                    element_list |
                    bool_ |
                    lit("null");

                char const* exclude = " ();\"\n\r\t";
                string = '"'
                    > +lexeme[char_ - char_(exclude)]
                    > '"';

                // Return: double
                number = double_ |
                    float_ |
                    int_;

                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(object);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(pair);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(members);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(element_list);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(elements);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(value);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(string);
                BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(number);
            }

            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, json_object(), Skipper > object;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, json_pair(), Skipper > pair;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, json_members(), Skipper > members;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, json_array(), Skipper > element_list;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, json_array(), Skipper > elements;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, json_value(), Skipper > value;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, std::string(), Skipper > string;
            boost::spirit::qi::rule < Iterator, double(), Skipper > number;
        };
      }
    }

//    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
//        signal_processing::parsing::json_object,
//        (std::vector < signal_processing::parsing::json_members >, children)
//    )
//
//    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
//        signal_processing::parsing::json_members,
//        (std::vector < signal_processing::parsing::json_pair >, items)
//    )
//
//    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
//        signal_processing::parsing::json_array,
//        (std::vector < signal_processing::parsing::json_value >, list)
//    )

    void parse ( std::string const& file )
    {
        typedef signal_processing::parsing::json_grammar < std::string::const_iterator, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type > configuration_grammar;
        configuration_grammar input; // Input grammar
        signal_processing::parsing::json_object parsed_data;

        std::string::const_iterator iter = file.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator end = file.end();
        bool r = boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse ( iter, end, input, boost::spirit::ascii::space, parsed_data );

        if ( ! r || iter != end)
        {
            // Report the next 30 characters
            std::string::const_iterator some = iter + 30;

            if ( some > end )
            {
                some = end;
            }

            std::string context(iter, some);
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
            std::cout << "stopped at: \": " << context << "...\"\n";
            std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        }
    }

    int main(int,char**)
    {
        std::string input ( "{\r\n       \"Event\": {\r\n                \"attribute_a\": 0.0002,\r\n                \"attribute_b\": 2e-005,\r\n                \"attribute_c\": 0.022\r\n        }\r\n}" );

        parse ( input );

        return 0;
    }
```

Which outputs:

```
localhost stov # ./stov
<object>
  <try>{\r\n       "Event": {</try>
  <members>
    <try>\r\n       "Event": {\r</try>
    <pair>
      <try>\r\n       "Event": {\r</try>
      <string>
        <try>\r\n       "Event": {\r</try>
        <success>: {\r\n               </success>
        <attributes>[[E, v, e, n, t]]</attributes>
      </string>
      <value>
        <try> {\r\n                </try>
        <string>
          <try> {\r\n                </try>
          <fail/>
        </string>
        <number>
          <try> {\r\n                </try>
          <fail/>
        </number>
        <object>
          <try>{\r\n                "</try>
          <members>
            <try>\r\n                "a</try>
            <pair>
              <try>\r\n                "a</try>
              <string>
                <try>\r\n                "a</try>
                <success>: 0.0002,\r\n         </success>
                <attributes>[[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, a]]</attributes>
              </string>
              <value>
                <try> 0.0002,\r\n          </try>
                <string>
                  <try> 0.0002,\r\n          </try>
                  <fail/>
                </string>
                <number>
                  <try> 0.0002,\r\n          </try>
                  <success>,\r\n                "</success>
                  <attributes>[0.0002]</attributes>
                </number>
                <success>,\r\n                "</success>
                <attributes>[0.0002]</attributes>
              </value>
              <success>,\r\n                "</success>
              <attributes>[[[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, a], 0.0002]]</attributes>
            </pair>
            <pair>
              <try>\r\n                "a</try>
              <string>
                <try>\r\n                "a</try>
                <success>: 2e-005,\r\n         </success>
                <attributes>[[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, b]]</attributes>
              </string>
              <value>
                <try> 2e-005,\r\n          </try>
                <string>
                  <try> 2e-005,\r\n          </try>
                  <fail/>
                </string>
                <number>
                  <try> 2e-005,\r\n          </try>
                  <success>,\r\n                "</success>
                  <attributes>[2e-05]</attributes>
                </number>
                <success>,\r\n                "</success>
                <attributes>[2e-05]</attributes>
              </value>
              <success>,\r\n                "</success>
              <attributes>[[[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, b], 2e-05]]</attributes>
            </pair>
            <pair>
              <try>\r\n                "a</try>
              <string>
                <try>\r\n                "a</try>
                <success>: 0.022\r\n        }\r\n</success>
                <attributes>[[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, c]]</attributes>
              </string>
              <value>
                <try> 0.022\r\n        }\r\n}</try>
                <string>
                  <try> 0.022\r\n        }\r\n}</try>
                  <fail/>
                </string>
                <number>
                  <try> 0.022\r\n        }\r\n}</try>
                  <success>\r\n        }\r\n}</success>
                  <attributes>[0.022]</attributes>
                </number>
                <success>\r\n        }\r\n}</success>
                <attributes>[0.022]</attributes>
              </value>
              <success>\r\n        }\r\n}</success>
              <attributes>[[[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, c], 0.022]]</attributes>
            </pair>
            <success>\r\n        }\r\n}</success>
            <attributes>[[[[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, a], 0.0002], [[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, b], 2e-05], [[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, c], 0.022]]]</attributes>
          </members>
          <members>
            <try>\r\n        }\r\n}</try>
            <pair>
              <try>\r\n        }\r\n}</try>
              <string>
                <try>\r\n        }\r\n}</try>
                <fail/>
              </string>
              <fail/>
            </pair>
            <fail/>
          </members>
          <success>\r\n}</success>
          <attributes>[[[[[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, a], 0.0002], [[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, b], 2e-05], [[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, c], 0.022]]]]</attributes>
        </object>
        <success>\r\n}</success>
        <attributes>[[[[[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, a], 0.0002], [[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, b], 2e-05], [[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, c], 0.022]]]]</attributes>
      </value>
      <success>\r\n}</success>
      <attributes>[[[E, v, e, n, t], [[[[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, a], 0.0002], [[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, b], 2e-05], [[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, c], 0.022]]]]]</attributes>
    </pair>
    <success>\r\n}</success>
    <attributes>[[[[E, v, e, n, t], [[[[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, a], 0.0002], [[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, b], 2e-05], [[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, c], 0.022]]]]]]</attributes>
  </members>
  <members>
    <try>\r\n}</try>
    <pair>
      <try>\r\n}</try>
      <string>
        <try>\r\n}</try>
        <fail/>
      </string>
      <fail/>
    </pair>
    <fail/>
  </members>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[[[E, v, e, n, t], [[[[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, a], 0.0002], [[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, b], 2e-05], [[a, t, t, r, i, b, u, t, e, _, c], 0.022]]]]]]]</attributes>
</object>
```

**Unicode**

I understand that the SVN build of boost::spirit now supports UTF8; try googling `BOOST_SPIRIT_UNICODE`. You can support 'unicode' (as microsoft calls it) right now using the wide string support in the library.

**Disclaimer**

I am working on Linux. YMMV.

Comment: While we're on the subject, I take it you have examined (and rejected) json_spirit? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented

Comment: The json_spirit used Boost Spirit v1. I am trying to update this for v2.

Comment: The only thing that does not sit well is inheriting from STL vector. All the documentation I have read have said that it is not a good design decision since the STL vector class lacks a virtual destructor.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the only case where inheriting a class from a parent class with a non-virtual destructor is a problem is when delete is called on the base class, which means the derived class's destructor isn't called. I don't think that will happen here.

Comment: I have spent some time trying to recode the problem with typedefs, and I can't find a way.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. This is the first time I have seen where inheriting from std::vector is required to parse data. It seems that this is required due to the nature of the grammar.

Comment: My pleasure. You may want to revisit this to find out how Qi works with containers: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have written [a UNICODE-aware JSON parser in Spirit v2 just recently](https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/tree/q16227680), here's a [testcase](https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/blob/q16227680/test.cpp) that parses your sample:

```
#include <sstream>
#include "JSON.hpp"

// util
static JSON::Value roundtrip(JSON::Value const& given) {
    return JSON::parse(to_wstring(given));
}

void roundtrip_test()
{
    auto 
        document = JSON::readFrom(std::istringstream(
                    "{\r\n"
                    "       \"Event\": {\r\n"
                    "             \"attribute_a\": 0.0002,\r\n"
                    "\"attribute_b\": 2e-005,\r\n"
                    "\"attribute_c\": 0.022\r\n"
                    "}\r\n}")),
        verify = roundtrip(document);

    std::cout << verify << "\n";
    std::cout << "document <=> verify equal:     \t" << std::boolalpha << (document == verify)                       << "\n";
    std::cout << "document <=> verify text match:\t" << std::boolalpha << (to_string(document) == to_string(verify)) << "\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
{"Event":{"attribute_a":0.0002,"attribute_b":2e-05,"attribute_c":0.022}}
document <=> verify equal:      true
document <=> verify text match: true
```

Some more API samples:

1. Object initializer expressions for 'immediate' JSON documents:

   ```
   void initializer_test()
   {
       using namespace JSON;

       const Array arr { 
           L"text", 
           42,
           Object { { L"dummy", Null() } } 
       };

       auto radius = as_double(arr[1]);

       auto const document = Object {
               { L"number", 314e-2 },
               { L"string", L"hello\ngoodbye" },
               { L"array" , arr },
               { L"bool" , False() },
               { L"radius", radius },
               { L"area", radius * radius * 3.14 },
               { String { 10, L'=' }, String { 10, L'*' } }
       };

       std::cout << document[L"bool"]   << std::endl;
       std::cout << document[L"number"] << std::endl;
       std::cout << document[L"string"] << std::endl;
       std::cout << document[L"array"]  << std::endl;
       std::cout << document[L"bool"]   << std::endl;
       std::cout << document[L"radius"] << std::endl;
       std::cout << document[L"area"]   << std::endl;
       std::cout << document            << std::endl;
   }
   ```
2. e.g. [this sample input](https://github.com/sehe/spirit-v2-json/blob/q16227680/testcases/test1.json) which passes the roundtrip test:

   ```
   {
       "Image": {
           "Width":  800,
           "Height": 600,
           "Title":  "View from 15th Floor",
           "Thumbnail": {
               "Russian":  "На берегу пустынных волн",
               "Escapes": "Ha \"\u0431\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0433\u0443\" shows up \\similar\\.\r\b\n",
               "берегу": "Russian",
               "Dummy": null,
               "Yummy": false,
               "Tummy": true,
               "Url":    "http://www.example.com/image/481989943",
               "Height": 125,
               "Width":  "100"
           },
           "IDs": [116, 943, 234, 38793]

       }
   }
   ```
3. This visitor example that transforms some JSON nodes: [How to manipulate leaves of a JSON tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093940/how-to-manipulate-leaves-of-a-json-tree/16096095#16096095)