# How to parse using boost if it is not json, but similar to it?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

I have an application that reads some parameters from a json file, but now the file has changed (it is not my decision). The file looks pretty the same, but instead of `{}` it has `[]`, so if until now it looked like

```
{
  "A":
  {
    "a":"a",
    "b":"b"
  }
}
```

now it is like this:

```
[
  "A":
  [
    "a":"a",
    "b":"b"
  ]
]
```

My application is written in C++, so I have used boost to parse the json file, but now I am looking for a new parser, is there a way to do it with boost?

I have started to search, but I have also asked the question thinking that maybe someone may help me faster than me finding the answer. Thanks

Comment: You could be lazy and simply replace characters from your input, and then process it exactly as you do now. Then check if there is a noticeable decrease in performance.

Comment: "My application is written in C++, so I have used boost to parse the json file" – no, you definitely don't *have to* use Boost.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: true, I do not have to use boost, but I've used it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Yet Another YAML/Mustache/JSON/... derivative.

Without a formal spec it's hard to actually assess what effort would be required, but here's a list of implementations of similar grammars in Boost Spirit, with varying amounts of feature completeness:

- [How to parse mustache with Boost.Xpressive correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122557/how-to-parse-mustache-with-boost-xpressive-correctly/24131286#24131286) <-- this is likely your best matching demonstration
- [Parse a substring as JSON using QJsonDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991232/parse-a-substring-as-json-using-qjsondocument/15991893#15991893) (minimal subset, use something like this to transform the input to proper JSON, e.g.?)
- [Reading JSON file with C++ and BOOST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746109/reading-json-file-with-c-and-boost/27749360#27749360) A full featured JSON parser (with AST and escapes but no comments)

Applications of a toy JSON parser implementation:

- [replace only some value from json to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711850/replace-only-some-value-from-json-to-json/17712300#17712300)
- [How to manipulate leaves of a JSON tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093940/how-to-manipulate-leaves-of-a-json-tree/16096095?s=4|0.0000#16096095)
- more